# Locally Testing Azure Mobile Auth - invalid jwt signature

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication, azure-mobile-services, jwt

I am playing with an Azure Mobile Apps backend (nodeJS), as discussed [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#Introduction). I have been using the default web setup configuration to develop my mobile app, but now I want to customise the cloud backend functionality, so I have created a local backend with the Azure-Mobile-Apps [SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node).

I logged in with my mobile app (using the authorization aspect of the Azure client SDK) and then captured the AuthToken.

I then constructed a Postman HTTP POST request, with these headers:

```
ZUMO-API-VERSION = 2.0.0
x-zumo-auth = eyJ0eX000000000000000000000000000000.eyJ000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000000000-000000000_00000_00000
```

NB: my tokenm doesn't actually have all those zeros, it looks like a valid token.

However, the POST request's response is:

> {
>     "name": "JsonWebTokenError",
>     "message": "invalid signature"
>   }

I thought this might be because the Auth token was generated by a different Service (the default backend rather than my project running on localhost). So I initialised a Client with localhost and tried to Authenticate with that, but I got:

> JS: Error Logging in! Error: Logging in with the selected authentication provider is not enabled
>   chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png", source: data:text/html,chromewebdata (12)

## Update:

I have found my WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY from `https://myApp.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml` and added it to my `azureMobile.js file`, which is in the same directory as my `app.js` file. It looks like this:

```
console.log("Test");
module.exports = {
    cors: {
        origins: ['localhost']
    },
    data: {
        provider: 'mssql',
        server: '127.0.0.1',
        database: 'mytestdatabase',
        user: 'localDemo',
        password: 'myPassword'
    },
    logging: {
        level: 'verbose'
    },
    auth: { secret: 'xzy0000000000000000000000000000000000' },
};
```

However, I still get the same result. Is there a way of telling whether my azureMobile file is being correctly referenced, or whether something else is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To validate JWT tokens locally that were created by a hosted service, you need to obtain the signing key that is used. You can obtain this by opening a browser to https://mobile-service-name.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml and finding the value for WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY. Take this value and configure your local server by creating (or updating) a file called azureMobile.js in the root of your project with the following content:

```
module.exports = {
    auth: { secret: 'value from WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY' }
};
```

It's recommended to exclude this file from deployment by adding azureMobile.js to your .gitignore file.

Comment: Thanks! I have done that and found my `WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY` and added it to my `azureMobile.js` file, which is in the same directory as my app.js file. However, I still get the same result. Is there a way of telling whether my azureMobile file is being correctly referenced, or whether something else is wrong? Any other ideas I would be really grateful!

Comment: I've realized that I broke this process a release or two ago. Added an issue on github that explains and gives a workaround - https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/issues/444.

Comment: I am afraid that even with that property enabled, I am getting the issue. Either my `azureMobile.js` file isn't being recognised (is there a way to check this) or something else is wrong, do I need to set any of the auth provider's signing secrets? e.g. the token I am using is a facebook token, do I need to specify the `APPSETTING_WEBSITE_AUTH_FB_APP_ID` or the `APPSETTING_WEBSITE_AUTH_FB_APP_SECRET` ?

Comment: I haven't even specified that I am using Authentication, and that fb is a provider in my backend.

Comment: Where did you obtain the token, i.e. which service signed it? You can put a console.log in your azureMobile.js to ensure it is being picked up. Alternatively, another workaround is to put validateTokens: false in the auth section of the configuration, just for local development.

Comment: The token is just from a standard hosted Azure Mobile Service (not the one I am testing on localhost). I have quite a lot of functionality based around changing behaviors based on whether they are logged in or not, so I really need to get it working.

Comment: I have just updated my question, please see the `azureMobile.js` file. I have added a `consol.log` which isn't firing. Do I have to reference/import that file somewhere in the project?

Comment: There is an active issue on github for showing exceptions that are raised from azureMobile.js. Currently, exceptions are swallowed - we'll fix this soon. Having said that, your file looks fine and should execute ok. You can move the config to the azure-mobile-apps top level function, i.e. var mobileApp = require('azure-mobile-apps')({ config }) just for testing. Also, try setting auth: { validateTokens: false }

Comment: Hmm, still no luck, [Here](https://github.com/georgeedwards/TestAzureBackend) is my repo. If I try adding `var mobileApp = require('azure-mobile-apps')({ config })` to my app.ts, then I get an error - `ReferenceError: config is not defined`, so I just put `var mobileApp = require('azure-mobile-apps')`. Which hasn't made a difference. I am not sure that my azureMobile.js file is being read

Comment: I didn't mean to literally put "config" in there... I meant to put your configuration object in there. Try putting a breakpoint in your azureMobile.js file using node-inspector and stepping into it using the node-debug command.

Comment: Awesome! that seems to have been an issue! I am now getting `{
  "name": "JsonWebTokenError",
  "message": "jwt audience invalid. expected: urn:microsoft:windows-azure:zumo"
}` How do I setup the jwt audience ?

Comment: I have followed up with a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944104/setting-jwt-audience-in-azure-mobile-apps-backend)