# Setting jwt audience in Azure Mobile Apps backend

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am playing with an Azure Mobile Apps backend (nodeJS), as discussed [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#Introduction). I have been using the default web setup configuration to develop my mobile app, but now I want to customise the cloud backend functionality, so I have created a local backend with the Azure-Mobile-Apps SDK.

I logged in with my mobile app (using the authorization aspect of the Azure client SDK) and then captured the AuthToken, using a live managed backend setup.

When I then come to try and authorise a request, I get the following issue:

> { "name": "JsonWebTokenError", "message": "jwt audience invalid. expected: urn:microsoft:windows-azure:zumo" }

Following on from: [Locally Testing Azure Mobile Auth - invalid jwt signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864189/locally-testing-azure-mobile-auth-invalid-jwt-signature/37866808#37866808)

How can I set the jwt audience?

Comment: How are you creating the JWT in the local case?

Comment: @AdrianHall the JWT is borrowed from the hosted instance - http://xyz.azurewebsites.net - copy and paste job into postman which then sends http requests to the localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the audience and issuer, use the auth:{} object in your azureMobile.js.  You can decode the JWT at jwt.io to see what the audience and issuer are, then do:

```
auth: {
    audience: '<your audience>',
    issuer: '<your issuer>'
};
```

Some good references:

- [My blog post on Custom Auth](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/08/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-5-custom-authentication/)
- [The main configuration reference](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/global.html#configuration) (which azureMobile.js exports)